# Merging features from different layers by field value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge

I have various layers with polygons which each represent a land use class (e.g. "roads", "vegetated terrain", "water", etc.) These layers have fields which further classify the features' land use (e.g. "bike path", "forest", "lake").

I'd like to re-classify information from all layers into new categories ("paved area", "roofs", and others). I will be combining features with different field values from various layers for that.

Is there an easy way to do this in QGIS? So basically:

1. Layer 1, field subclass = X
2. Layer 1, field subclass = Y
3. Layer 2, field subclass = Z

should be merged into a new shapefile representing the output class I want.

Comment: You could merge the layers into one (which will have overlapping geometries), then use an expression like `subclass IN yourlist` to extract all relevant features.